# different results when openning an image into numpy array using cv2.imread and PIL.Image.open

Tags: opencv, python-imaging-library

I am trying to open an image and turn it into a numpy array.

I have tried:
1) cv2.imread which gives you a numpy array directly
2) and PIL.Image.open then do a numpy.asarray to convert the image object.

Then i realise the resulting array from the same picture is different, please see the attached screenshots.
[cv2.imread](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCjGW.png)
[PIL.Image.open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5a2V.png)

I would expect the color channel should always have the same sequence, no matter the package, but I do not seem to be able find any documentation for pillow reagarding this.

Or am I just being silly? Thanks in advance for any suggestion!!!

Answer (score 6):

I don't know anything about PIL but, contrary to just about every other system in the world, OpenCV stores images in BGR order, not RGB. That catches every OpenCV beginner by surprise and it looks like that's the case with your example.

Comment: I'd say it catches those who can't be bothered to read the documentation before they use some function or library they're not familiar with. IIRC the one for `imread` has contained the note "In the case of color images, the decoded images will have the channels stored in B G R order." for a pretty long time.

Comment: "contrary to just about every other system in the world ", isn't that how they are stored in vram  in most systems ? ...

Answer (score 2):

**Opencv**

```
image = cv2.imread(image_path, 1)
image_cv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

**Pillow**

```
image_from_pil = Image.open(image_path).convert("RGB")
image_pillow = numpy.array(image_from_pil)
```

`image_np` equals `image_cv`

Notes: While reading a JPEG image, `image_np` and `image_cv` may be little different because the libjpeg version may be different in OpenCV and Pillow.

Comment: This is neat and clear.

Comment: What is `image_from_pil`?

Answer (score 0):

As SSteve and Xin Yang correctly say, the main problem could be that cv2 returns spatial domain (pixels) in BGR color plane, instead of usual RGB. You need to convert the output (reverse the order in channels' axis or use `cv2.cvtColor`).

Even after the color plane conversion, the output might not be the same. Both PIL and cv2 use libjpeg under the hood, but the outputs of libjpeg do differ for different versions. Read [this research paper](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/3531536.3532962) for reference. Based on my experiments I can say that the libjpeg version used by PIL is unpredictable (differs even on two identical MacBook Pro 2020 M1 using brew and the same Python and PIL version).

If it does matter and you want to have control over which libjpeg/libjpeg-turbo/mozjpeg version is used for compression and decompression, use [jpeglib](https://pypi.org/project/jpeglib/). It is still in beta, but the production release is coming.